# Residue of $f(z) = \frac{\cos(z+i)-1}{(z+i)^4} $

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

The function $$f(z) = \frac{\cos(z+i)-1}{(z+i)^4} $$ has one singular point in $\Bbb C$.

**i) Identify the point:**

The point is $z+i=0$ hence $z=-i$ is the point.

**ii) Show the singularity is a pole**

We can write $f(z)$ as $f(z)=\frac{\cos(z+i)-1}{(z-(-i))^4}=\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-(-i))^4}$ hence this is a pole of order 4.

**iii) calculate the order of the pole**

This is a pole of order 4.

**iv) Evaluate the residue of $f$ at this pole.**

The residue is equal to:$$\frac{\phi^{(m-1)}(z_0)}{(m-1)!}$$

Where $\phi^{m-1} =\sin(z+i)$ and $m$ is order so $m=4$

Residue is: $$\frac{\sin(-i+i)}{3!}=0$$

**Is this correct?**

Comment: For the order of the singularity, pay attention, because the numerator has a zero at the pole to. By considering the Taylor expansion of cosine, you should get a order of 2.

Comment: @Zardo Oh my god, I didn't even know the numerator could have a pole!

Edit: Or actually you are saying it cancels two out

Comment: Yes, it cancels out. The numerator has a root of order $2$ while the denominator has a root of order $4$. The fraction therefore has a pole of order $2 = - (2-4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct - the pole has order $2$. You may also notice that:
$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{\cos(z+i)-1}{(z+i)^4},z=-i\right)=\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cos z-1}{z^4},z=0\right) = 0$$
since $\cos z$ is an even function:
$$ \frac{\cos z-1}{z^4} = \frac{-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\ldots}{z^4}=-\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{24}+o(z).$$

Comment: Hmmm I read the comment that was left by Zardo, but could you clarify why I have order $2$ rather than $4$

Comment: @SkiesBurn: because $z=-i$ is a zero of order four for $(z+i)^4$, as well as a zero of order two for $\cos(z+i)-1$.

Comment: What is the defining factor for zeroes of order m in the numerator. I can't see immediately why it is of order $2$ in the numerator. (Whereas order $4$ in denominator is via theorem)

Comment: @SkiesBurn: what is the Taylor series of $1-\cos z$ at $z=0$? It starts with $\frac{z^2}{2}$, hence $z=0$ is a double zero of $1-\cos(z)=2\sin^2\frac{z}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand.